# POST some text and images with time to PHP service in Objective -C

Tags: ios, objective-c

Made 3 view controllers. FIRST with the name vc1 and second with vc2 and third with vc3. in vc1 there is some textfield data and in vc2 there are some image views and buttons under it, these images first to convert to base64.Third vc it also have some text field now i want to submit all the data from textfield of vc1 and vc3 and all the images from vc2 with time in milliseconds to a php web service. I have written some code but I'm not getting any response. can anyone help me plzz. My code is:

```
enter code here`NSString *dateString1 = @"16-05-2017 14:35";
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter1 = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter1 setDateFormat:@"dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm"];
NSDate *dateFromString1 = [[NSDate alloc] init];
dateFromString1 = [dateFormatter1 dateFromString:dateString1];
NSTimeInterval timeInMiliseconds1 = [dateFromString1 timeIntervalSince1970]*1000;
NSString *timestamp1=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f",timeInMiliseconds1];
NSLog(@"time in mililsecond is %.00f",timeInMiliseconds1);

NSString *dateString2 = @"16-05-2017 14:35";
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter2 = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter2 setDateFormat:@"dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm"];
NSDate *dateFromString2 = [[NSDate alloc] init];
dateFromString2 = [dateFormatter2 dateFromString:dateString2];
NSTimeInterval timeInMiliseconds2 = [dateFromString2 timeIntervalSince1970]*1000;
NSString *timestamp2=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f",timeInMiliseconds2];
NSLog(@"time in mililsecond is %.00f",timeInMiliseconds2);

NSString *dateString3 = @"16-05-2017 14:35";
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter3 = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter3 setDateFormat:@"dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm"];
NSDate *dateFromString3 = [[NSDate alloc] init];
dateFromString3 = [dateFormatter3 dateFromString:dateString3];
NSTimeInterval timeInMiliseconds3 = [dateFromString3 timeIntervalSince1970]*1000;
NSString *timestamp3=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f",timeInMiliseconds3];
NSLog(@"time in mililsecond is %.00f",timeInMiliseconds3);

NSString *dateString4 = @"16-05-2017 14:35";
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter4 = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter4 setDateFormat:@"dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm"];
NSDate *dateFromString4 = [[NSDate alloc] init];
dateFromString4 = [dateFormatter4 dateFromString:dateString4];
NSTimeInterval timeInMiliseconds4 = [dateFromString4 timeIntervalSince1970]*1000;
NSString *timestamp4=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f",timeInMiliseconds4];
NSLog(@"time in mililsecond is %.00f",timeInMiliseconds4);

NSString *dateString5 = @"16-05-2017 14:35";
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter5 = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter5 setDateFormat:@"dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm"];
NSDate *dateFromString5 = [[NSDate alloc] init];
dateFromString5 = [dateFormatter5 dateFromString:dateString5];
NSTimeInterval timeInMiliseconds5 = [dateFromString5 timeIntervalSince1970]*1000;
NSString *timestamp5=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f",timeInMiliseconds5];
NSLog(@"time in mililsecond is %.00f",timeInMiliseconds5);

NSString *dateString6 = @"16-05-2017 14:35";
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter6 = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter6 setDateFormat:@"dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm"];
NSDate *dateFromString6 = [[NSDate alloc] init];
dateFromString6 = [dateFormatter6 dateFromString:dateString6];
NSTimeInterval timeInMiliseconds6 = [dateFromString6 timeIntervalSince1970]*1000;
NSString *timestamp6=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f",timeInMiliseconds6];
NSLog(@"time in mililsecond is %.00f",timeInMiliseconds6);

NSString *post = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"name=%@&email=%@&phone=%@&propertytitle=%@&propertyfor=%@&propertytype=%@&propertyprice=%@&propertyavail=%@&landarea=%@&noofrooms=%@&noofbathrooms=%@&nooffloors=%@&description=%@&structureofproperty=%@&structureofflooring=%@&wallsstructure=%@&doorsstructure=%@&=electricalstructure=%@&location=%@&country=%@&city=%@&imgurl1=%@&timestamp1=%@&imgurl2=%@&timestamp2=%@&imgurl3=%@&timestamp3=%@&imhurl4=%@&timestamp4=%@&imgurl5=%@&timestamp5=%@&imgurl6=%@&timestamp6%@",_name.text,_email.text,_Phone.text,_propertytitle,_propertyfor,_propertytype,_propertyprice,_propertyavail,_landarea,_noofrooms,_noofbathrooms,_nooffloors,self.description,_structureofproperty,_structureofflooring,_wallsstructure,_doorsstructure,_electricalstructure,_Location,_but1.titleLabel.text,_but2.titleLabel.text,_imgurl1,timestamp1,_imgurl2,timestamp2,_imgurl3,timestamp3,_imgurl4,timestamp4,_imgurl5,timestamp5,_imgurl6,timestamp6];
NSData *postData = [post dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding allowLossyConversion:YES];
NSString *postLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [postData length]];
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];
[request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@" my url"]];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[request setValue:postLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
[request setHTTPBody:postData];
NSURLSession *session = [NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration:[NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration]];
[[session dataTaskWithRequest:request completionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {
    NSString *requestReply = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
    NSLog(@"requestReply: %@", requestReply);
  resume];
```

Comment: Does your request look the way you want it to when you start the data task?  Does the web service see your post?

Comment: it is showing nothing in debug area like that requestreply:            . @PhillipMills

Comment: I'm just facing problem in images i don't know how i should post them to service.can u help me? @PhillipMills